# MySql equivalent of MS access DatePart

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to convert a MS Access query to mysql query but in the `SELECT` part I found a DatePart function which selects the year from the table tbl_trade. I understand that we have inbuilt functions in mysql like YEAR(), EXTRACT() etc but it seems that I cannot use them as

```
SELECT YEAR(tbl_trade.create_date) from tbl_trade;
```

It gives an error

```
Unknown table 'tbl_trade' in field list
```

Also I do not know how to implement the 3rd and 4th parameter of the DatePart function in mysql.
You can find more details about DatePart function from https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php

In the end, I wish to be able to implement this

`SELECT DatePart("yyyy", tbl_trade.create_date,1,2) FROM tbl_trade`

Comment: Your first query should work. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=733840dabb43e84f6e8357140730ae3d) What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent is [`extract`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract). It takes a variety of [intervals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals).

```
select create_date, extract(year from create_date)
  from tbl_trade;

+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| create_date         | extract(year from create_date) |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |                           2019 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |                           2019 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```

As for changing the definitions of the week and year, you can pass [various modes to `week`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week).

```
-- Mode 7: Week starts on Monday. Week 1 is the first with a Monday.

select create_date, week(create_date, 7) from tbl_trade;
+---------------------+----------------------+
| create_date         | week(create_date, 7) |
+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |                   53 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |                   53 |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Or do it by setting [`default_week_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format) to affect all date functions.

```
set default_week_format = 7;

select create_date, extract(week from create_date) from tbl_trade;
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| create_date         | extract(week from create_date) |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |                             53 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 |                             53 |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```

And for fine control there is [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
-- %v is mode 3. First DOW is Monday. First week is has 4 days or more.

select create_date, date_format(create_date, '%W week %v') from tbl_trade;
+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
| create_date         | date_format(create_date, '%W week %v') |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | Wednesday week 01                      |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | Wednesday week 01                      |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
```